# Power BI Filtering Data with an Exclusive Condition

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

This has been a curly question I have been asked and I am unsure how to tackle it in PowerBI (the user I am helping is specifically using it so I don't have the option to lean on a more comfortable programming language).

We have a situation where (for example) they are wanting to filter for compound names based upon a selected treatment and a response value from that treatment. So far so good with basic slicers.

HOWEVER they then wish to see ONLY those compounds that have a response in the correct range for the specifically chosen treatment, and if another treatment has a response in that range too, they wish to drop that compound.

For example, the following table is something I synthesized that gives an easy example:

| Compound | Treatment | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 13.80 |
| 1 | B | 8.25 |
| 1 | C | 9.22 |
| 1 | D | 10.50 |
| 2 | A | 11.66 |
| 2 | B | 8.42 |
| 2 | C | 12.63 |
| 2 | D | 9.63 |

In this case, I have a checkbox slicer for treatment and a slider slicer for response. If I specify a range of 11 - 14 for the response, the current behaviour is that I have compound 1 with treatment A and compound 2 with treatment A and C. Then if I select Treatment A for the treatment slicer, I just have both compound 1 and 2 with treatment A.

The desired behaviour would be to have ONLY compound 1 with treatment A because compound 2 has treatment C within this range too.

I feel like this is probably doable with an appropriate DAX but I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: What visual shows you result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the `Compound` with the less treatment(s) only.

Create a new measure:

```
Rank = 
RANKX(
    'Table',
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Table'),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Table'[Treatment])
    ),
    ,
    TRUE,
    SKIP
)
```

It ranks the number of results (ie. lines in the Table) for a given Compound.

Then, you add this new measure in the Filters bar, in "Filters on this visual" zone. And you set the filter to 1.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: The one thing I would want to change about this, is the compound that has the Ranks equal to the number of treatments selected. So in this example it is "Rank is 1" but is there a way to get "Rank is the count of selected treatments"?

Comment: You want *the best* compound per treatment selected ?

Because for Treatment A, the method above returns compounds 1 and 2. So, how do you chose between the two if you want one compound only per treatment. Is it the one with the smallest `Response` ?

If yes, it means the ranking method should rank response time, grouped by compounds.

Comment: No, essentially in this case we have the A B C D treatments, and we want the compounds that are within the range for the selected treatments only. If they have a treatment that is in the range, but the treatment isn't selected then we don't want to show them.